# How can I add tabs to a view outside the action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have a layout where I need tabs [inside a sub-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12416617/403455), not in the action bar.  I.e., The tabs do not apply to the entire screen display, only to one of the panes.

How can I do this in Android 4.0+?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the support library and a FragmentTabHost. Google has an example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html). In your layout file you can embed the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` that's shown in the example inside another layout, such as a pane.

Another option is to use scrollable tabs. They also can be imbedded anywhere in a layout. Google gives a code example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging). The view that you will imbed in your pane is the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` with a `android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip` as it's subview. This example also has a sample project that you can download (the example project doesn't have the scrollable tabs imbedded inside another layout, but it's a good starting point).